# ¿Cómo separar por distintos caracteres partes de un texto con regex?

Tags: python, regex

Tengo una cadena de texto. Lo que quiero es identificar aquellas palabras que tengan ":" y que me las de como un dic.

```
text = "Esta es una prueba. Socios: Martin, joaquin. Aca continua el texto."
if re.search(r"^w:.$", text):
    variables = (re.search(r"^w:.$", text).split(':')
    dic = {}
    dic[variables[0] = variables[1]
else:
    print("Match not found")
```

El output que estoy buscando: {'Socios': 'Martin, joaquin'}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En primer lugar, el patrón que usas no alcanza a resolver el problema, es correcto a la hora de buscar la "clave" pero no así el valor, ya que capturará el texto completo y lo que entiendo que buscas es que sea solo hasta el punto. Las expresiones regulares por defecto son "hambrientas" y llegan siempre hasta el último caracter del patrón, por lo que en este caso habrá que usar otra técnica:

```
regex = r"(\w+:.*?(?=\.))"
```

El patrón sería **`w+`** una palabra, seguida de **`:`**, y por último **`.*?(?=\.)`** cualquier caracter de 0 a cualquier longitud hasta el primer **`.`** (punto). Esto último se lo conoce como [Positive Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Finalmente tú código, simplificando y ordenando algunas cosas, podría ser:

```
import re

dic = dict()
regex = r"(\w+:.*?(?=\.))"
text = "Esta es una prueba. Socios: Martin, joaquin. Aca continua el texto."

match = re.search(regex, text)
if match:
    variables = match[0].split(":")
    dic[variables[0]] = variables[1].strip()
else:
    print("Match not found")

print(dic)
```