# Cómo separar por distintos caracteres partes de un texto con regex Version2 en Python

Tags: python, regex

Estoy trabajando con regex. Necesito modificar el regex para que me de el output que coloco abajo a modo ejemplo.

Anteriormente hice una pregunta similar ([¿Cómo separar por distintos caracteres partes de un texto con regex?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/290765/c%c3%b3mo-separar-por-distintos-caracteres-partes-de-un-texto-con-regex)) que fue respondida con exito, el problema fue que a medida que empece a evaluar todos los str que tenía, empecé a ver que el '.' no era la solucion para cortar el str con regex ya que `DNI: 39.770.622` rompe con esa estructura.

texto:

```
texto = 'Acto Privado del 22/5/19. Socios: Francisco Hernán Martinez, soltero, empleado, 25/7/1996, DNI: 39.770.622; y Sandra Lopez, casada, empresaria, 22/2/1971, DNI: 21.604.835; ambos argentinos y domiciliados en Carlos Casares 1083 Castelar, Pcía. de Buenos Aires. Denominación: “12 SABORES\xa0S.R.L.”. Duración: 99 años. Objeto: La explotación comercial del negocio de rotisería, mediante el servicio de elaboración, expendio y delivery de todo tipo de comidas para llevar y bebidas y la comercialización de todo tipo de productos alimenticios vinculados al objeto social. Capital: $\xa020.000.- Administración: uno o mas gerentes, en forma individual e indistinta, socios o no, por todo el tiempo que dure la sociedad. Cierre de Ejercicio: 31/3. Gerente: Sandra Lopez, con domicilio especial en la sede social. Sede Social: Urquiza 56, piso 15°, depto. “G” C.A.B.A. Autorizado según instrumento privado Constitutivo de fecha 22/05/2019 Fabiana Karina Eustasi - Habilitado D.N.R.O. N°\xa011453'
```

Output que necesito:

```
[
    'Acto Privado del 22/5/19',
    'Socios: Francisco Hernán Martinez, soltero, empleado, 25/7/1996, DNI: 39.770.622; y Sandra Lopez, casada, empresaria, 22/2/1971, DNI: 21.604.835; ambos argentinos y domiciliados en Carlos Casares 1083 Castelar, Pcía. de Buenos Aires',
    'Denominación: “12 SABORES\xa0S.R.L.”',
    'Duración: 99 años',
    'Objeto: La explotación comercial del negocio de rotisería, mediante el servicio de elaboración, expendio y delivery de todo tipo de comidas para llevar y bebidas y la comercialización de todo tipo de productos alimenticios vinculados al objeto social',
    'Capital: $\xa020.000',
    'Administración: uno o mas gerentes, en forma individual e indistinta, socios o no, por todo el tiempo que dure la sociedad',
    'Cierre de Ejercicio: 31/3',
    'Gerente: Sandra Lopez, con domicilio especial en la sede social',
    'Sede Social: Urquiza 56, piso 15°, depto. “G” C.A.B.A. Autorizado según instrumento privado Constitutivo de fecha 22/05/2019 Fabiana Karina Eustasi - Habilitado D.N.R.O. N°\xa011453'
]
```

codigo:

```
cuerpo_regex = re.findall(r'\S+:[^.]+', texto)
```

Output:

```
['Socios: Francisco Hernán Martinez, soltero, empleado, 25/7/1996, DNI: 39',
 'DNI: 21',
 'Denominación: “12 SABORES\xa0S',
 'Duración: 99 años',
 'Objeto: La explotación comercial del negocio de rotisería, mediante el servicio de elaboración, expendio y delivery de todo tipo de comidas para llevar y bebidas y la comercialización de todo tipo de productos alimenticios vinculados al objeto social',
 'Capital: $\xa020',
 'Administración: uno o mas gerentes, en forma individual e indistinta, socios o no, por todo el tiempo que dure la sociedad',
 'Ejercicio: 31/3',
 'Gerente: Sandra Lopez, con domicilio especial en la sede social',
 'Social: Urquiza 56, piso 15°, depto']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema no es sólo que aparezcan números separados por puntos en algunos lugares. Es que tienes además varias abreviaturas como "Pcía.", "depto.", etc.. las cuales terminan por punto pero no dan por terminada una frase.

### Primera aproximación

Si no fuera por esas abreviaturas, sería mucho más sencillo pues todas las frases (salvo una) terminan por un punto **seguido de un espacio**. La que única excepción es una frase que termina por `".-  "`, es decir, un punto, un guión y un espacio.

Dejando de lado de momento el problema de las abreviaturas, podrías usar `re.split()` para dividir tu entrada según la expresión regular `r"\.-? "`, que es un punto seguido opcionalmente de un guión y después un espacio. Esto cubre correctamente todos los "finales de frase" y al dividir de esta forma (si no hubiera abreviaturas) conseguirías lo que buscas. Mira:

```
>>> re.split(r"\.-? ", texto)
['Acto Privado del 22/5/19',
 'Socios: Francisco Hernán Martinez, soltero, empleado, 25/7/1996, DNI: 39.770.622; y Sandra Lopez, casada, empresaria, 22/2/1971, DNI: 21.604.835; ambos argentinos y domiciliados en Carlos Casares 1083 Castelar, Pcía',
 'de Buenos Aires',
 'Denominación: “12 SABORES\xa0S.R.L.”',
 'Duración: 99 años',
 'Objeto: La explotación comercial del negocio de rotisería, mediante el servicio de elaboración, expendio y delivery de todo tipo de comidas para llevar y bebidas y la comercialización de todo tipo de productos alimenticios vinculados al objeto social',
 'Capital: $\xa020.000',
 'Administración: uno o mas gerentes, en forma individual e indistinta, socios o no, por todo el tiempo que dure la sociedad',
 'Cierre de Ejercicio: 31/3',
 'Gerente: Sandra Lopez, con domicilio especial en la sede social',
 'Sede Social: Urquiza 56, piso 15°, depto',
 '“G” C.A.B.A',
 'Autorizado según instrumento privado Constitutivo de fecha 22/05/2019 Fabiana Karina Eustasi - Habilitado D.N.R.O',
 'N°\xa011453']
```

Pero debido a las abreviaturas se dan más trozos de los deseados. Por ejemplo, la línea "de Buenos Aires" no debería haber sido separada, pero lo ha sido porque antes había "Pcía. de Buenos Aires", de modo que el punto con espacio se ha tomado por fin de frase.

No es el único caso. Hay más abreviaturas similares en tu texto, y otros casos como el acrónimo `C.A.B.A.` y otros.

### La solución

Se puede utilizar el mecanismo llamado *negative look-behind* que consiste en decirle a la expresión regular que encaje sólo si *no aparece antes* otra expresión regular. Este mecanismo se logra anteponiendo `(?<!xxxx)` a nuestra expresión regular, siendo `xxxx` lo que no queremos que aparezca.

En nuestro caso podríamos poner `r"(?<!Pcía)\.-? "` y de este modo encajará con cualquier secuencia de punto, guión opcional y espacio *que no esté precedida por la palabra Pcía*.

De forma análoga podemos excluir el resto de abreviaturas que puedan aparecer.

Para hacerlo genérico, podemos tener una lista con todas las abreviaturas esperables y usarla para construir dinámicamente la expresión regular.

```py
abreviaturas = ["Pcía", "depto", "D.N.R.O", "C.A.B.A"]
regex = "".join("(?<!{})".format(abr) for abr in abreviaturas) + r"\.-? "
```

la variable `regex` contendrá de este modo la expresión regular deseada que en este caso sería:

```
>>> regex
'(?<!Pcía)(?<!depto)(?<!D.N.R.O)(?<!C.A.B.A)\\.-? '
```

Ya sólo queda usarla con `re.split()`:

```
>>> re.split(regex, texto)
['Acto Privado del 22/5/19',
 'Socios: Francisco Hernán Martinez, soltero, empleado, 25/7/1996, DNI: 39.770.622; y Sandra Lopez, casada, empresaria, 22/2/1971, DNI: 21.604.835; ambos argentinos y domiciliados en Carlos Casares 1083 Castelar, Pcía. de Buenos Aires',
 'Denominación: “12 SABORES\xa0S.R.L.”',
 'Duración: 99 años',
 'Objeto: La explotación comercial del negocio de rotisería, mediante el servicio de elaboración, expendio y delivery de todo tipo de comidas para llevar y bebidas y la comercialización de todo tipo de productos alimenticios vinculados al objeto social',
 'Capital: $\xa020.000',
 'Administración: uno o mas gerentes, en forma individual e indistinta, socios o no, por todo el tiempo que dure la sociedad',
 'Cierre de Ejercicio: 31/3',
 'Gerente: Sandra Lopez, con domicilio especial en la sede social',
 'Sede Social: Urquiza 56, piso 15°, depto. “G” C.A.B.A. Autorizado según instrumento privado Constitutivo de fecha 22/05/2019 Fabiana Karina Eustasi - Habilitado D.N.R.O. N°\xa011453']
```

**Nota**. En mi solución, aparece una entrada "Denominación: ", que en tu pregunta no aparece como parte del resultado (aparece en realidad como parte de la línea anterior, pegada al final). Supongo que ha sido un error por tu parte. Aclara si, por alguna razón especial, esta línea no debería aparecer como separada, sino como pegada a la anterior. Podría resolverse con un *negative look-ahead*.

### Actualización: Acrónimos y búsqueda de abreviaturas

Un acrónimo es una serie de letras mayúsculas separadas por puntos, como "C.A.B.A" o "D.N.R.O". En el código anterior éstos se introducían explícitamente como abreviaturas adicionales, pero puede ser más eficiente escribir una expresión regular que los detecte a todos, para así no tener que meterlos uno a uno. La expresión regular sería simplemente algo que termine en Mayúscula-punto-Mayúscula-punto (incluso se podría ser más breve y decir que termine en punto-Mayúscula-punto).

Con este enfoque el código sería:

```py
abreviaturas = ["Pcía", "depto", r"[A-Z]\.[A-Z]\."]
regex = "".join("(?<!{})".format(abr) for abr in abreviaturas) + r"\.-? "
re.split(regex, texto)
```

El resto de abreviaturas sí que habría que introducirlas "a mano", o al menos recopilarlas todas para analizar si siguen algún tipo de patrón (pero es poco probable).

Para encontrar "posibles abreviaturas" podemos buscar todas las palabras formadas por solo letras (no cifras) y terminadas en punto seguido de espacio (y que no tengan un punto delante), con una expresión regular como la siguiente:

```py
>>> posibles = re.findall(r"(?<!\.)\b[a-záéíóúüñç]+\.(?= )", texto, re.IGNORECASE)
>>> set(posibles)
{'Aires.', 'Pcía.', 'años.', 'depto.', 'social.', 'sociedad.'}
```

Lo de `set()` es para eliminar duplicados. Ahora habría que examinar el resultado para determinar cuáles son verdaderamente abreviaturas y cuáles palabras normales al final de una frase.

Comment: Fue un error, ya lo corregí a "denominación". Muchas gracias. Para despejar dudas... lo ideal sería que analice todas las excepciones que puede haber primero e ir almacenándolas en una lista verdad? Porque voy a correr el script para 60,000 textos.

Comment: Pues sí, la idea es que la lista `abreviaturas` contenga todas las que hayas detectado. Quizás convendría una búsqueda preliminar de todas las palabras terminadas en punto (para lo que puedes usar otra expresión regular) pero te van a salir muchas! Por otro lado los acrónimos quizás no haya que meterlos "uno a uno" en la lista. Se puede hacer una expresión regular que los detecte, como por ejemplo "Mayuscula-punto-Mayuscula-punto" (`r"[A-Z]\.[A-Z]\."`)

Comment: @MartinBouhier He actualizado la respuesta con más ideas sobre esto último